# Firefoxdriver does not launch int test unit c#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I have te code below:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest3
{
    private static FirefoxDriver _webDriver;
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
    private static string _baseUrl;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }

    public static string BaseUrl
    {
        get
        {
            return _baseUrl;
        }
        set
        {
            _baseUrl = value;
        }
    }

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void Initialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        _webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        _webDriver.Quit();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void OpenGoogle_PageOpenSuccessfully()
    {
        BaseUrl = "http://www.google.es";
        _webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BaseUrl);
    }
}
```

When debugging the test _webDriver = new FirefoxDriver is left wondering and does not launch.

I'm use Selenium-Webdriver and c# unit test (mstest)

Are there any issue with firefoxdriver?

Answer (score 1):

I update to Selenium Web Driver 2.33 an working successfully.

Thanks